# Fetch data that is not a registered react-admin resource

Tags: react-admin

Using react-admin, I have build an ExpressJS API including a GraphQL endpoint. All my resources in react-admin are using the graphql data provider. For a specific resource, I'm looking to fetch some configuration from my API endpoint to generate the form based on the context. I will try to create a mock example as I can't use the actual application's lingo.

For example, if I edit resource Post, and I assign a specific type "Photo", then I want some specific metadata to be saved in the form. My issue is the specific metadata object is coming from the API configuration for type "Photo". So if I select type "Photo", I want to save "Capture Date", "Camera Make", "Camera Model", etc.

The backend configuration would probably be in the form of a JSON schema describing the fields, the label, the key and the type of input (text or password).

TLDR: I want to fetch a configuration in the API and use it in the app to generate a list of form inputs. How can I do this without registering the call as a resource, since I don't feel like it is?

**Edit**
I haven't tried anything yet as I was asking a theoretical question to see if anybody had a "proper way" to suggest. My two options were the following:

1. Create a Resource for the PostType and it would simply return the list of fields as a JSONschema when called with GET_ONE. This would make use of the dataProvider to do the fetching.
2. Simply use fetch in my form and call my API endpoint directly.

Comment: Interesting question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added clarifications in the Edit1 of the original question.